# Parent the root of an etree to the element of another etree

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

Given two element trees, I'd like to insert the root of one of them into some element of the other one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
t1 = et.parse('test1.xml')
t2 = et.parse('test2.xml')
t2.find('your/element').append(t1.getroot())
t2.write('test3.xml')
```

And an example:

```
In [1]: from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
In [2]: !cat test1.xml
<el1>
  <el2></el2>
</el1>
In [3]: !cat test2.xml
<foo>
  <bar>
  </bar>
</foo>
In [4]: t1 = et.parse('test1.xml')
In [5]: t2 = et.parse('test2.xml')
In [6]: t2.find('bar').append(t1.getroot())
In [7]: t2.write('test3.xml')    
In [8]: !cat test3.xml
<foo>
  <bar>
  <el1>
  <el2 />
</el1></bar>
</foo>
```